# Linked List to file

Tags: java

So basically I need to make a program which stores cd information and I need to write it to file.I need to be able to:

Add, 
Edit or 
Delete the information

So I used the Linked List but when written to file the contents are a little shoddy.

Plus it overwrites the info every time I want to add more info.

This is what I have thus far.

```
   public class Project1
{
    static String userIn;   //Determines what the user wants to do in the application

    static String[] info = new String[] {};     //Stores album info

    static LinkedList <String> list = new LinkedList<String> ();        //Array that stores the info to file

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);                       //Takes input from keyboard

    static String album;                //Takes in the album name

    static String artist;               //Takes in the artist name

    static String date;                 //Takes in the release date of the album

    static  FileWriter fstream;         //Used to write to file

    static BufferedWriter out;          //Used to write to file

    static String file_name ;           //The name of the file is stored 

    static String search ;              //Takes input 

    public void welcome()           //Main menu of the program where user makes selection

            {//Method will be used as a main menu asking the user what he/she would like to do

                System.out.println("*****MAIN MENU*****");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To add your album to the system please enter the word add");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To edit a album in your collection please insert the word edit");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("If you would like to delete a album please insert the word delete");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To search for a particular album by the CD name please insert the word cd");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("To search for your album by artist name insert the word artist");

                userIn = scan.next();       //Takes user input to decide what action to take

            }//Close of welcome method (Serving as main menu)

        public void adding()                //Used to add info to the linked list
            {//Start of adding method
                if(userIn.equals("add"))    //Starts the add method
                {//Start of if statement

                    System.out.println("*****ADD MENU*****");
                    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the artist");
                    artist = scan.next();   //Stores the artist name
                    System.out.println("Please enter the album name");
                    album = scan.next();    //Stores the album name
                    System.out.println("Please enter the release date");
                    date = scan.next();     //Stores the release date

                    list.add(artist);       //Adds the artist variable to file
                    list.add(album);        //Adds album variable to file
                    list.add(date);         //Adds the date variable to file

                    System.out.println("Album name,Artist Name,Date of release " + list);   //Displays the linked list

                    System.out.println();   //Prints Blank Line

                    file_name = "output.txt";       //File where info is stored to

                     try 
                    {//Start of try and catch method to catch fileNotFound Exception

                         fstream = new FileWriter(file_name);       //Creates an instance of the fileWriter class

                         out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);         //Creates instance of the BufferedWriter class

                         out.write(artist);                 //Adds artist variable to file

                         out.write(album);                  //Adds album variable to file

                         out.write(date);                   //Adds date variable to file

                         out.close();                       //Closes the input stream
                    } 
                     catch (IOException e)                  //Catches FileNotFoundException
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }//End of try/catch

                }//End of if statement              

            }//End of adding method

                public void edit()
                    {//Starts the edit method
                        if(userIn.equals("edit"))
                        {//Start of if statement which searches for the album through a matching word

                            System.out.println("*****EDIT MENU*****");

                            System.out.println("Please enter the name you would like to edit");

                            search = scan.next();       //Takes input to match files that need to be edited

                            if(search.equals(album))    //Matches the name the user wants edited to the name in the list
                            {//Start the if statement that 

                                System.out.println(list);       //Displays the list containing the info

                                list.removeAll(list);           //Removes all the input to allow user to edit

                                System.out.println("Please enter new name of the artist ");     
                                artist = scan.next();   //Allows user to add a new artist
                                System.out.println("Please enter new album name ");
                                album = scan.next();    //Allows user to add a new album
                                System.out.println("Please enter new release date");
                                date = scan.next();     //Allows user to add a new release date


                                list.add("," + artist);     //Adds the artist variable to the linked list
                                list.add("," + album);      //Adds the album variable to the linked list
                                list.add( date);            //Adds the date to the variable to the linked list

                                System.out.println("Album name,Artist Name,Release Date" + list);       //Displays the Linked List

                                  try 
                                    {//Start of try and catch method to catch fileNotFound Exception

                                         fstream = new FileWriter(file_name);       //Creates an instance of the fileWriter class

                                         out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);         //Creates instance of the BufferedWriter class

                                         out.write(artist);                 //Adds artist variable to file

                                         out.write(album);                  //Adds album variable to file

                                         out.write(date);                   //Adds date variable to file

                                         out.close();                       //Closes the input stream
                                    } 
                                     catch (IOException e)                  //Catches FileNotFoundException
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();


                                    try 
                                    {//Start
                                        out.close();        //Closes the stream 
                                    }//End 
                                    catch (IOException z) 
                                    {//Start of catch statement
                                    z.printStackTrace();
                                    }//End of try catch

                                    }

                                    }//End of if statement
                                    else
                                    {//Start of 

                                    System.out.println("Album not found");      //Displays if the user input could not be linked to info in the linked list

                                }//End of if else statement

                        }//End of if statement     

                }//End of method

                public void delete()        //Used to delete info from the linked list
                {//Start of delete method
                    if(userIn.equals("delete"))
                    {//Matches user input to verify if correct method

                        System.out.println("*****DELETE MENU*****");

                        System.out.println("Please enter the name to delete");

                        search = scan.next();   //Takes in the name to match with linked list   

                        System.out.println("To continue insert 1");

                        int uSure = scan.nextInt(); //Takes input to verify if deletion is desired

                        if(uSure==1)
                        {//Starts 

                            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the album you would like to delete");  //Displays the file contents to the user
                            list.removeAll(list);       //Deletes the contents of the list

                        }//End of second if statement

                        if(search.equals(album))
                        {//Searches for info in linked list according to user input.
                            System.out.println(list);
                            list.remove();  //Removes info from the linked lists
                            System.out.println("Album deleted");

                          try 
                            {//Start of try and catch method to catch fileNotFound Exception

                                 fstream = new FileWriter(file_name);       //Creates an instance of the fileWriter class

                                 out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);         //Creates instance of the BufferedWriter class

                                 out.write(artist);                 //Adds artist variable to file

                                 out.write(album);                  //Adds album variable to file

                                 out.write(date);                   //Adds date variable to file

                                 out.close();                       //Closes the input stream
                            } //end of try 
                             catch (IOException e)                  //Catches FileNotFoundException
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();


                            }//End of try/catch
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Album not found");
                    }//End of if statement

                }//End of first if statement

            }//End of method    


            public void search()
            {//Start of search method

                if(userIn.equals("search"))                     
                {//Matches user input to verify if correct method
                    System.out.println("*****SEARCH MENU*****");

                    System.out.println();               //Prints out a blank line

                    System.out.println("Please insert the name of the album");

                    search = scan.next();               //Takes user input

                    if(album.equals(search))            //Matches user input to info in linked list
                    {
                    System.out.println(list);       //Matches user search to info in linked list
                    }
                    else
                    {//Ends the if statement

                    System.out.println("Album name could not be found");  //Displayed if user input could not be matched with info in the linked list

                }//End of second if statement

              }//End of first if statement

         }//End of search method

            public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException 
            {//Starts the main method which runs the application

            Project1 cd = new Project1();       //Making an instance of the class

            cd.welcome();   //Runs the welcome method
            cd.adding();    //Runs the adding method
            cd.edit();      //Runs the edit method
            cd.delete();    //Runs the edit method
            cd.search();    //Runs the search method

        }//End Of Main method

}//End Of Class
```

I have also attempted a bit of this using an array list if it would be of more help

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Are you trying to keep a catalog of multiple albums or just one?
Are you just trying to write this information to the file as a list of strings?

Comment: `"...contents are a little shoddy."` In what way? Are you reading the file and storing the information in a data structure? I recommend read the file -> store the info -> Do user interaction, make changes to data structure -> Write to file when user wants and/or on exit.

Comment: It's not writing more than one album into the file it overwrites the previous info

Comment: but, do you want it to write more than one album to the file?

Comment: multiple albums not just one...yes I'm trying to write as a list of string 'cause of the fact that there are many attributes to one album.In regards to the shoddy writing to file-It gives me random characters

Answer (score 1):

If the file doesn't need to be human editable or have performance constraints, you can use [Java's serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) to write the array to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit or delete, you have to overwrite ALL the contents. You are only adding one entry. Have a single method which re-writes all the contents of the LinkedList to a file after adding, editing or deleting an entry.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If its an information that the **same java program writes and reads** then use **serialization**.

**2.** Else use File.

**3.**
       You need to append the data rather than over-writing it in the file.

```
  File f = new File("d:\\viv.txt");
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);  // true is to enable appending
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

  bw.append("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in addition to the file stuff already mentioned. Those strings are added to the list by reference. When you change the string, you are changing it in the list as well. They need to be new instances of string when you add them to the list.

2nd, I would create a class to encapsulate the data for an album. None of the strings should be static. Then add (NEW) instances of the Album class to your list. Then, override the ToString() method inside the Album class to print the information the way you need it.

Also, there is no real reason to use a linked list here if you are always appending to the list, a plain array based list will be fine (especially if you need quick access to each element). Searches will be big-Oh(n) on a linked-list, they are constant on an array based list. The only time you need a linked-list is where you need efficient inserts somewhere other than the end of the list and where you will be reallocating the size frequently. Not that all of that really matters on a modern computer and in a small application.